# IE/Firefox/Opera not picking up stylesheet - Webkit okay

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, opera

I'm doing a website for a client and for some strange reason when loading the page in IE/Firefox/Opera, the stylesheet doesn't load properly.

When loading the site in WebKit (Chrome, Safari, Mobile Chrome, Mobile Safari) the page loads fine.

I've check that the doctype is fine, the links don't have any typos, they all link up correctly in the source.

I cant for the life of me figure out why it doesn't work!

Please help!

http://almostinspired.net 
and 
http://almostinspired.net/wp-content/themes/almostinspired/style.css

Comment: It looks like Firefox is seeing your stylesheet, but breaking partway through it. So far I've determined that it gets to line 115 but not 161! You should take out chunks between there...maybe the @font-face declarations, and see what happens.

Comment: amazing! it worked when i took out a h6 selector. strange how that works, hey?

thanks so much for your help! 

how did you determine what section firefox was breaking the stylesheet at?

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. Can any help me to solve this please. Here I am unable to understand  what exactly I have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that your CSS file *is*, in fact, being loaded by every browser, but is only being partially processed by some browsers. This might be because of an improperly formatted stylesheet.

I've determined that these browsers reach line 115, but don't quite make it to 161. I'd try removing selectors in between there until you determine which one is causing problems.

And this is what I did to figure this out:

I opened up your site in Firefox and went to 'Inspect Element.' It was clear to me that the most obvious thing that was getting messed up was your #wrapper div. This thing was styled at around line 160 in your stylesheet, which gave me a line number that it wasn't getting to. I looked around on different elements to find the lowest number it was getting to, and the lowest I found was 115. And that's what I used to infer this solution.

Comment: Nice tip on getting to the bottom of issues like this.