# stylesheet wont load in Firefox , IE and Opera

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, firefox, font-face

My wordpress website won't load correctly in FF , IE and Opera But in chrome it's OK.
I have looked at these two questions but they didn't helped:
[IE/Firefox/Opera not picking up stylesheet - Webkit okay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167070/ie-firefox-opera-not-picking-up-stylesheet-webkit-okay)
[CSS not loading in Firefox, Opera and IE - Chrome and Safari works just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846868/css-not-loading-in-firefox-opera-and-ie-chrome-and-safari-works-just-fine)
any help?

Comment: The link to your site does not work.

Comment: @suspectus It seems like a server error. The link works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of font!
I had declared a rtl true type font in style.css like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NewSampleFont’;
    src:url('fonts/NewSampleFont.eot?#’) format(‘eot’),    
          url('fonts/NewSampleFont.woff') format('woff'),
          url(‘fonts/NewSampleFont.ttf’) format(‘truetype’); 
}
```

But i forget to add the **same code** to the first begining of my `reset.css` file.